# My Theme.css isn't loading?

Tags: html, css

On my website the theme.css is basically ignored...

It just doesn't use it.
FYI it was working before too, i have no idea why it isn't working anymore..

HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TFCase.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div id="navbar">
            <a class="nav1" href="/">HOME</a>
            <a class="nav2" href="dice.php">DEPOSIT</a>
            <a class="nav3" href="support.php">SUPPORT</a>
    <div id="steamLogon">
        <?php

            require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';

            if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

            loginbutton("small"); //login button

            }  else {

            include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
            //Protected content
            logoutbutton(); //Logout Button
        } 
        ?>
    </div>
        </div>

    <div id="caselogo">
        <a href="/">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page">
    <h2></h2>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS Code

http://pastebin.com/irURMSzd

Comment: How is it not working? Did you change or move anything? Is your theme.css at the same level as your html file? If you check chrome dev tools in the network tab, are there any 404 errors?

Comment: Yes the're in the same place, there the only 2 files that aren't folders.

Comment: So this is index.php and in the same folder is theme.css? You could try putting an absolute url to your theme.css to see if that works. Absolute URLs start with `/` and is the full path from your domain to the file.

Comment: So for example it would be `/theme.css` if your theme.css is located at `www.example.com/theme.css`.

Comment: Unless you actually link to your page as well, the code you provided should load the theme.css - if it doesn't work, then there is probably a problem on your server,

Comment: What you see in inspector? do you get any erros? 404 or what?